# When distributing a Linux application, can you include dynamic libraries alongside your binary?

Tags: linux, installation

dumb question about distributing a Linux application. I know we have Flatpak for this but I am curious.

Say you're creating a GUI application that depends on some dynamic dependencies. As I understand it, Flatpak will include those dependencies with your app image such that they are separate to the ones available by the system.

Additionally, packaging formats like `deb` and `rpm` will trigger the package manager to download missing shared libraries.

That said, could you just distribute your executable along with the dynamic libraries (included within the `tar.gz` archive people would download)?

```
/myapp.tar.gz
  /bin
    myapp
  /lib
    libssl3.so
    qt5
```

So people could just unpack it somewhere and run the executable without a package manager or container solution?

Literally just

```
curl -L --url https://.../linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar -xvzf - -C $HOME/.local/myapp
$HOME/.local/myapp/bin/myapp
```

Perhaps the executable could use a system supplied dependency first and if not present use the local one?

Does this approach work?

If it does work, why don't developers do this instead of distributing via many package formats?

Does it break the terms of OSS licenses to distribute libraries like this?

Comment: Does it break the terms of which of a dozen OSS licenses? Most OSS licenses don’t have limitations on how you get your package to the customer only if the source code must be available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do this, but to successfully launch the application `ld-linux` will need to find the libraries.

This may be a simple as providing a launcher script to set LD_SEARCH_PATH to include the directory where the files reside, or LD_PRELOAD to force load them.

Order of dependencies can be done by putting your directory after the system library directories in LD_SEARCH_PATH

So `$HOME/.local/myapp/bin/myapp` is replaced with a `sh` script file that sets some variables and then `exec`s  `$HOME/.local/myapp/bin/myapp.bin` or `$HOME/.local/myapp/lib/myapp.bin`

Read the man page for ld-linux for more information.

Licensing, well you'll need to reed the licenses, but most library licenses allow this.

Comment: Given the overhead of software developers distributing multiple formats (deb, rpm, etc) - it seems preferable to just distribute one form of your application and target all distros. I'm curious why this approach isn't more popular with developers? I guess it's a bit wasteful to have duplicate copies of a library, but they are are small anyway. Is there some disadvantage I am missing out on?

Comment: The biggest hassle with wrapping up other peoples libraries is every time they release a security patch all your customers need a patch, or a new version of the app from you.